# Drop down button is not responding with selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I want to click on drop down button and select one among one and click on it.I tried by many ways but it is not working. Attached image of html code, Anyone help me regarding this.
Below is my code which i tried

```
driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_dropdown")).click();

    /*List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"homepages_item_AccountManagerDashboard\"]")); 

    for (WebElement element: allElements)
    {
          System.out.println(element.getText());
    }*/
```

Comment: try //span[@id='homepages_dropdown'][@class='dropdownTitle']

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Try below xpath to select element by text:
'//*[.='Account manager's dashboard']'

Answer (score 0):

Just use "Select" to create an object that handles dropdowns etc. You can use "Select" to select element by it's text, index and a bunch of other options. It's the easiest way to handle such elements as dropdown and comboboxes.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_dropdown"))).selectByVisibleText("Your option's text");
```

Comment: I don't believe that this solution will work because the element is not a Select element in the DOM

Comment: You are correct, my bad for not seeing it before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the sharpest way to do it, but if you can't get developers to make it a specific select element via HTML it may have to do. I have stuff like this in my solution where there are custom dropdowns.

You can start by creating a dropdown element and then click a single record in it if that's what you're trying to do, in your case it looks like it is the span within the highlighted button element, so you can do something like the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_dropdown")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li//a[@id='homepages_item_AccountManagerDashboard']").click();
```

The above statements will click the dropdown then click the element with the id of `homepages_item_AccountManagerDashboard`.

You can also create a function that clicks any li of based off of a parameter you pass into a method you create, consider this if you may select many options in your dropdown.

```
public void SelectItem(string itemText)
{
    var dropdownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_dropdown"));
    var selectionItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='" + itemText + "']");
    dropdownElement.Click();
    selectionItem.Click();
}
```

This is only really a valid option if you are working through the Page Object Model, but it's the best way to make things work consistently long term.

Answer (score 0):

To click on `Dropdown` button and `Select` the `Option` with text as **`Analytics`** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='homepages']/button/span[@id='homepages_dropdown']")).click();
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='homepages']/ul/li/a")); 
for (WebElement element : allElements)
  if(element.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Analytics"))
  {
      element.click();
      break;
  }
System.out.println("Option with text as Analytics is selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself,Below code worked

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("homepages_dropdown")));
// drop down
driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_dropdown")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
// selecting configuration
driver.findElement(By.id("homepages_item_ConfigurationHomepage")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```